# iOS No iCloud account is configured

Tags: ios, swift, icloud, cloudkit

I am currently trying to get the iCloud ID of the user. It worked for about 2 months but today when i re-tested, it is not working anymore.

I have the following code:

```
func iCloudUserIDAsync(complete: @escaping (_ instance: CKRecord.ID?, _ error: NSError?) -> ()) {
    let container = CKContainer.default()

    container.fetchUserRecordID() {
        recordID, error in
        if error != nil {
            print(error!.localizedDescription)
            complete(nil, error! as NSError)
        } else {
            print("fetched ID \(recordID?.recordName ?? "")")
            complete(recordID, nil)
        }
    }
}
```

And i am getting the "No iCloud account configured" error altough i am signed into iCloud on my iPhone and i also enabled iCloud Drive.

It is working on my other iPhone (7 Plus) but on my main development XS it is giving me this error

Comment: Before calling `fetchUserRecordID`, call `accountStatus` on your container. What is the result?

Comment: I found I had to sign out of iCloud, sign back into iCloud, and restart the device, to get my code to see my iCloud account properly.

Comment: @matt Yes, this is the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I logged out of iCloud and logged back in and then in worked.

@matt answered correctly